# Application Insight shows no results found

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

I have Azure Web App which is connected to Application Insights resource. I have been using this for 2-3 years now. I used to see the requests and other information without any issue. I have published .NET 4.6.1 web app.

Today I realized that (visited app insights after long time) its not showing any data. If I choose any other table or time range (tried 7 days), I get the same result.

[image]

Below are settings in azure web app related to application insights:

[image]

I see the same issue in many of my web apps. Do I have to update any setting? Or how can I fix this?

Comment: Please refer [Troubleshooting no data - Application Insights for .NET/.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-troubleshoot-no-data)

Comment: Are you following any document to log data ? If yes, please share so that I can reproduce the same issue

Comment: I am not logging any custom data but just wanted to get the default information like requests. We were able to see requests information without explicitly logging it (referring screenshot 1).

Answer (score 0):

Could this be the reason: compared to previous versions of the web app we now included assembly Azure.Core.dll. Which has a reference that causes assembly System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll to be included. Which leads Azure to believe that you do your metrics yourself, using the Application Insights SDK. Which effectively disables the Auto-Instrumentation that you were probably relying on. We are facing a similar issue and are looking for a work-around.